# Network Switch Cisco 2960X not allowing WS-discovery

Tags: networking, switch, ip-camera, network-discovery

I've been trying to set up a Cisco 2960X switch with an IPcamera Panasonic WS-S1131. An .exe is used to obtain information from the camera and to set it up. However, this isn't working when connected to the switch. I know that the .exe uses WS-Discovery as a protocol.

When the camera is connected directly to the PC it has no issue, but as soon as it is connected through the switch the issues come back.

The computer is able to ping and access the camera's web ui when connected to the switch. They are part of the same VLAN.

Comment: do you know if the .exe [when used over a network] requires a specific port or something? or perhaps is getting blocked by a firewall either at the switch or back to the computer?

Comment: A switch in a default confirmation will not block any traffic. Consider testing with another switch or reviewing the Cisco switch's configuration for anything non-standard.